# need to create shopping cart price rule for buy 2 get 5% off and buy 3 get 10% off

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, price, rules, shopping

I wanted to give an offer to the users. If they buy the same product with qty 2 then 5% off and if they buy 3 then 10% off. I tried it with shopping cart price rules but only one shopping cart price rules works at the same time. Is there any way to achieve it. Please help.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried making 2 different rules? One for 5% and one for 10% and stop further rules processing?

Answer (score 0):

shopping cart rule not work for you if you create the two rule then both condition will be true and user will get combine 15% discount.you can use `tier price` for that  follow link how to use `tier price`

http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/catalog/product-price-tier.html

Comment: Could you not add a condition saying products in cart for that sku is 2 or 3?

Comment: how to add condition for `same product` sku condition?

Comment: Do I need to add for each product? I have more than 2000 products in my store..

Comment: I have tried with price rules and it works fine with one case.. But if I try to enable the 2nd price rule then only 2nd one is working and applying (BOTH RULES )15% off.. See how I have managed the same SKU http://prntscr.com/ar84cf

Comment: @Harry this is first thing i mention in my answer. the both rule will be applied either you have to custom work and set the discount or use tier price.

Comment: I got it working with shopping price rules.. was needed to set conditions there..

Comment: you add the sku condition but for both it is same because product is same so you both condition will be true again

Comment: Got it working.. As expected!!

Comment: @Harry good to know can you post your solution?

Answer (score 0):

Solution is :

For BUY 2 GET 5% - Create a shopping cart price rule, then under the Discount Amount * set your discount amount(in percentage) for eg. 5%

Under the "
Apply the rule only to cart items matching the following conditions (leave blank for all items)
"
set condition : 
If ANY  of these conditions are TRUE :

```
Quantity in cart  is  2
```

For BUY 3 or more GET 10% - Create a shopping cart price rule, then under the Discount Amount set your discount amount(in percentage) for eg. 10%

Under the "
Apply the rule only to cart items matching the following conditions (leave blank for all items)
"
set condition : 
If ANY  of these conditions are TRUE :

Quantity in cart  equals or greater than  3

"Quantity in cart" attribute checks the qty for same SKU.

That solved my problem.

I hope it will help someone. Thanks!